# Random array selector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a workout program that selects a random workout and musclegroup every time you start it. I have ran into trouble with selecting which musclegroup it's picking.

I would like it to pick one of the three arrays but right now the value of dice_roll is always equal to 2. Not sure where I have gone wrong.
Thanks for any help.

(OBS! Excuse my ugly code, it doesn't seem to be posting right so it may be excused!)

```
int main() 
{
    int muscleGroup;
    string chest[2] = {"Benchpress 4x2", "Pushups 10x4"};
    string legs[2] = {"Squat 8x4", "Leg extension 10x3"};
    string back[2] = {"Pullup 3x8", "Rows 10x3"};
    mt19937 generator; 
  
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);
    int dice_roll = distribution(generator);
    if (dice_roll == 0) 
    {
        cout << "You are training: Chest" << endl;
        cout << "Your exercises are going to be written below!" << endl;
    } 
    else if (dice_roll == 1) 
    {
        cout << "You are training: Legs" << endl;
        cout << "Your exercises are going to be written below!" << endl;
    } 
    else if (dice_roll == 2) 
    {
        cout << "You are training: Back" << endl;
        cout << "Your exercises are going to be written below!" << endl;
    }         
  
    // cin >> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to seed the generator. Easy and ugly way is `mt19937 generator(time(0));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your generator with a random seed.

You can do so using:

```
std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
```

You can find a larger code snippet and more details on the [cppreference uniform_int_distribution page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: Note that it won't work on MinGW, since their `random_device` always produces a same sequence.

Comment: It worked doing that! Thanks a lot, i'll have to do some reading on seeds because I have no clue why it worked.

Comment: @Alexanderrost the *seed* is what determines the sequence of the pseudo-random generator (in your case, the mersenne twister) - you can think of it as a "starting point". Given the same seed it will always produce the same sequence of numbers (which can be very useful). Seeding it with pure entropy guarantees a unique sequence every run.